# Conditionally open a modal in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to implement a functionality similar to what Facebook does with its photos. Here's the use case:

1. User goes to `/`—a page with a list of links
2. He clicks on a link
3. A modal window appears and the URL changes into `/people/:id`—where `:id` depends on what I clicked on.
4. When the user closes the modal the URL goes back to `/`
5. If the user goes directly to `/people/:id` he can see a full page and not a modal

I made an example AngularJS application that does that https://github.com/Gpx/conditional-modal. The problem is that is not testable. In particular see this code:

```js
// Listen to location changes
$scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (evt, next, current) {
  var match;
  // Is the new page /people/:id ?
  if (match = next.match(/\/people\/(\d)+$/i)) {
    evt.preventDefault(); // Don't change view

    // Show a modal
    var dialogScope = $scope.$new();
    dialogScope.person = $scope.people[match[1]];
    ngDialog.open({
      template: 'views/person.html',
      controller: 'PersonCtrl',
      scope: dialogScope
    });

    // Here comes the tricky part

    // When the modal gets closed we go back    
    dialogScope.$on('ngDialog.closed', function (e, $dialog) {
      window.history.pushState('', '', '/#/');
    });
    // We need to use setTimeout or we'll run into a Error: 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
    setTimeout(function() {
      window.history.pushState('', '', '/#/people/' + match[1] + '?skip');
    }, 5000);
  }
});
```

Any idea on what is the best approach to achieve this functionality?